# WhenEvent Issue with ParallelTable

Tags: differential-equations, parallelization, event-detection

I'm having a problem assigning the `WhenEvent` time value to a variable if `NDSolve` is iterated inside a `ParallelTable` as opposed to a `Table`

Minimum code example:

```
tMax = {0, 0, 0, 0};
ySol = ParallelTable[
  NDSolve[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == 5 i, y'[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[y[t] == 1, {tMax[[i]] = t, "StopIntegration"}]}, 
   y, {t, 0, 10}], {i, 1, 4}]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[y[x] /. ySol, {i, 1, 4}], {x, 0, Max[tMax]}]
```

I've tried using `DistributeDefinitions[tMax];` to no effect.

Comment: You probably want `SetSharedVariable[tMax];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works well.

```
tMax = {0, 0, 0, 0}; SetSharedVariable[tMax];
ySol = ParallelTable[NDSolveValue[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == 5 i, y'[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[y[t] == 1, {tMax[[i]] = t, "StopIntegration"}]}, y[x], {t, 0, 10}], {i, 1, 4}];
Plot[Evaluate@ySol, {x, 0, Max[tMax]}]
```

[image]

Curves extend beyond their endpoints, because `InterpolatingFunction` extrapolates the curves.  To truncate each curve at its respective `tMax`, use

```
Show[MapThread[Plot[#1, {x, 0, #2}, PlotStyle -> #3] &, {ySol, tMax, 
    Take[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], Length[tMax]]}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Having 4 cores or more, I'd use

```
ParallelEvaluate[tMax = 0];

ySol = ParallelTable[
  NDSolve[{y''[t] == -9.81, y[0] == 5 i, y'[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[y[t] == 1, {tMax = t, "StopIntegration"}]}, y, {t, 0, 10}], {i, 1, 4}
  , Method -> "EvaluationsPerKernel" -> 1]

Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. ySol], {x, 0, Max[ParallelEvaluate@tMax]}]
```

[image: Out]